# Vue Как отобразить input color c input number

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vue3

Как связать левую часть с вводом от пользователя цвета блока в `input color` и количества блоков с этим цветом в `input number` и связать их с правой частью где они должны отобразиться. Я понимаю что необходимо использовать `v-model`, собрать в массив, закинуть все это в `state`, а на странице с отображением вывести это через гетеры. Мне непонятна техническая реализация этого - как собрать этот массив, превратить этот массив в цветные квадраты с цветом и по количеству заданные в массиве, с учетом того что необходимо реализовать второе состояние - по нажатию кнопки перемешать нужно перемешать цветные квадраты между собой и вывести их в одну линию, при этом количество квадратов и их цвет, заданные пользователем, должны быть сохранены.

Comment: Почитайте про управление состоянием https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/state-management.html#simple-state-management-with-reactivity-api

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но вопрос не про управление состоянием, а как собрать массив и затем вывести данные. Дополнил свой вопрос.

Comment: Вот вам и необходимо придумать структуру state, которая соответствовала бы задаче.
проще, если input number и input color не формируют массив, а изменяют элементы готового массива. этот же массив используется при отрисовке правой стороны. Найдите в интернете материалы по MVC